# Are there any plants that shouldn't be planted near garlic?

Tags: companion-planting, crop-rotation, garlic

I recall reading something on companion planting and crop rotation that mentioned some crops shouldn't be planted near or where garlic or other alliums were planted. The reason was that those plants would have stunted growth.

Is this true and if so what plants are affected by this? Are there any plants that benefit from being grown in a location where garlic was?

Comment: my strawberries, chives, parsley, veronica prostrata, miniature rose, wooly yarrow and tulips don't seem to suffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my Companion Planting book, legumes, peas and potatoes should not be grown with or near garlic because it affects their flavour and growth. Everything else (carrots, etc) is fine, in fact, the garlic may well have a good effect on pests which affect other crops, such as carrot fly. There is an idea that planting garlic near roses means the roses have fewer diseases, in particular, blackspot, which doesn't thrive in the presence of sulphur - garlic accumulates sulphur as it grows, so in theory, it should have an impact, but I've not noticed any real difference.

Comment: Is there mention of not planting those things in the same spot that garlic was just grown in? Mine was harvested two weeks ago and I was planning on growing bush beans in its place.

Comment: I have also read that planting garlic with roses will make the rose scent stronger.

Answer (score 4):

I have planted garlic as a rabit deterrent around all my plants.  I didn't realize that garlic can cause stunted growth, but here is my data:

Plants that seen not to have been affected: tomoatoes, squash (various kinds)

Plants that are smaller than I would like: marigolds, some hot peppers, eggplants

I don't know if the lack of growth is due to the garlic or not.

Comment: Did the garlic have the desired deterrent effect on the rabbits? I have too many to control by more direct means, so this is a possibility, if it works. A great excuse to grow abundant quantities of my favourite flavouring!

Comment: Yes, it works well.  The trick is to use a three-pronged approach.  1) Plant garlic 2) Crush garlic and litter your garden with it and 3) Whenever you see the bunnies, run at them to give them a bit of a scare.